# SQL Exception Unhanded Code in ASp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was doing my ASP.Net project for my academic purpose and i am trying to retrieve an image stored in Database as binary to a grid view. And i am getting this error.

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in   
System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
```

And the keyword 'in' is coming from my session email =  admin@test.in

## So here is my entire code in asp c#, the default page , mypets.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;



public partial class mypets : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["petlyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
DbConnect db = new DbConnect();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridviewData();
    }
    //  if (Session["email"] == null)
    //  {
    //        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    //   }
    string m = Session["email"].ToString();
    email.Text = m;

    // string sql = "SELECT pic FROM pets WHERE email="+ (string)Session["email"] +"";

    // Image img = (Image)FindControl("petimage");
    // img.ImageUrl = "sql";

}

private void BindGridviewData()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string emai = Session["email"].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "select [imageid], [petname],[petsdis],[catgry] from [pets] where [email]=" + emai+ "";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            gvImages.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gvImages.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}





protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string cat = catgry.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string na = Session["email"].ToString();

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];
        HttpPostedFile img = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        //set the binary data
        img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            db.con.Open();
            //  db.cmd = new SqlCommand("update ureg set picture='" + fn + "' where email='" + (string)Session["email"] + "'", db.con);
            db.cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into pets(petname,email,catgry,mb,petsdis,pic) values(@PetName,@Email,@Catgry,@Mb,@PetDis,@Image) ", db.con);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PetName", petname.Text);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email.Text);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catgry", cat);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mb", mb);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PetDis", petsdis.Text);
            db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", imgbyte);

            db.cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            db.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Pet Details Successfully Added')</script>");
            con.Close();
            BindGridviewData();

        }


    }
}
```

}

**mypets.aspx**

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/akshara.masteAutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mypets.aspx.cs" Inherits="mypets" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

 <div class="padding100">
    <div class="container">
        <table class=" table-responsive" width="100%">

            <tr >
                <td width="60%" id="listpets">
                     <h1 class="common"> Your Pets</h1>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvImages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Pet ID" InsertVisible="False" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="petname" HeaderText="Pet Name" SortExpression="petname" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="petsdis" HeaderText="Discription" SortExpression="petsdis" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="catgry" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="catgry" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("imageid") %>'Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>




                </td>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <td width ="40%" id="addpets">
                    <h1 class="common"> Add Your Pets</h1>

                     <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                           <div class="col-md-9">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="email" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"  ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="petname" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                             Pets Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="petname" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="petname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="catagry" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                           Category</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="catgry" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="DOG" Value="Dog" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Beagle" Value="Beagle" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Boxer" Value="Boxer" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Bulldog" Value=" Bulldog" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Cocker Spaniel" Value="Cocker Spaniel" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Dalmatian" Value=" Dalmatian" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Doberman" Value=" Doberman" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- German Shepherd" Value=" German Shepherd " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Golden Retriever" Value=" Golden Retriever " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Husky" Value="  Husky" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Labrador" Value="Labrador  " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Mastiff" Value=" Mastiff " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Pomeranian" Value=" Pomeranian " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Pug" Value="Pug  " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Rottweiler" Value="Rottweiler  " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Saint Bernard" Value="Saint Bernard " />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Other Breeds" Value="Other Breeds " />

    <asp:ListItem Text="BIRDS" Value="Birds" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="CATS" Value="Cats" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Birman" Value="Birman" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- British Shorthair" Value="British Shorthair" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Oriental" Value="Oriental" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Persian" Value="Persian" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Ragdoll" Value="Ragdoll" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Russian Blue" Value="Russian Blue" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Siberian" Value="Siberian" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Sphynx" Value="Sphynx" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Other Cat Breeds" Value="Other Cat Breeds" />

         <asp:ListItem Text="OTHER PETS" Value="other pets" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="catgry" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="petsdis" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                           Discription</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="petsdis" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Discription" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="petsdis" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </div>
                        </div>



                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="mobile" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                               Owners Mobile No.</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="mb" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter your 10 digit number" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="mb" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="mobile" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Mobile Number Invalid" ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$" ControlToValidate="mb"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 
                        </div>     

                              <div class="col-md-9">           
                             <asp:Label ID="upl" runat="server"   Text="Upload Photo" CssClass="form-control"></asp:Label>  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  CssClass="fa-upload" />     
                                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add My Pet" CssClass="btn btn-success"  OnClick="Button1_Click"  />



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>






                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

        </div>
     </div>
     </asp:Content>
```

**ImageHandler.ashx**

```
     <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ImageHandler" %>

     using System;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Data.SqlClient;
     using System.Configuration;

     public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler {
     public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
    string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["petlyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select pic from pets where imageid=" + imageid, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr[0]);
    con.Close();
    context.Response.End();
}
public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a parameter instead of string concatenation like you do for the other commands.

Comment: Even using string concatenation, you need to surround email with single quotes like such: "select [imageid], [petname],[petsdis],[catgry] from [pets] where [email]='" + emai+ "'"

Comment: You need to differentiate between what is a string in C# and what will be a string in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding Your Error Message**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

This comes as a result of your actual e-mail address containing the word `IN` which is a keyword within SQL. Since you aren't using parameterziation or wrapping the value in quotes, SQL thinks you are trying to perform an `IN` query and blows up.

**Parameterization, Not Concatenation**

You really should be using parameterization to handle this as opposed to string concatenation for all of your queries, as it can not only leave you vulnerable to nastiness like SQL Injection, but it can help avoid issues with query syntax :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [imageid], [petname], [petsdis], [catgry] FROM [pets] WHERE [email]= @email";
// Add your parameter
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",Convert.ToString(Session["email"]));
// Execute here
```

and :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT pic FROM pets WHERE imageid= @image", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image",imageid);
// Execute here
```

Comment: OP describes where `in` comes from in the question.

Comment: Ah I hadn't seen that little line beneath. Either way, parameterization should resolve this issue as SQL is picking up the `in` within the email address.

Comment: After i done the above change, my imageid column is not reading

Comment: Are you sure that your querystring value in `context.Request.QueryString["ImID"]` is correct? This will be the value that is passed in.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid column name 'imageid'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'imageid'.
Source Error: 
Line 48:                 cmd.Connection = con;
Line 49:                 con.Open();
Line 50:                 gvImages.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 51:                 gvImages.DataBind();
Line 52:                 con.Close();

Comment: And you have placed a breakpoint within your code to check that the value is being read properly from the QueryString? Based off the syntax issue it sounds like this is a problem with your GridView not liking "imageid" or being unable to find it when it's being populated.

Answer (score -1):

if it is indeed the in, in the email, you could try to change it to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select [imageid], [petname],[petsdis],[catgry] from [pets] where [email]='" + email + "'";
```

for added security you should probably replace all ' characters with \' in email (though it is probably not necessary

Comment: For security use parameters for exactly the reason this errored in the first place - sql injection.